# isDaylightSavingTimeForDate causing fatal error

Tags: ios, runtime-error

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Routine triggering this error is:

```
// Calculate Timer Offset
let tz = NSTimeZone(name: inputTimeZone)
if tz!.isDaylightSavingTimeForDate(newDate!) {
     inputTimeOffset = inputTimeOffset + inputDayLightSaving
}
```

when DayLightSaving changes (newDate!/30th March). Both inputTimeOffset and inputDayLightSaving have a value of 3600.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting ("unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value") indicates you're doing inappropriate unwrapping.

Try changing your code to this:

```
// Calculate Timer Offset
if let unwrappedDate = newDate as? NSDate
{
    if let tz = NSTimeZone(name: inputTimeZone)
    {
        if tz.isDaylightSavingTimeForDate(unwrappedDate) {
            inputTimeOffset = inputTimeOffset + inputDayLightSaving
        } 
    } else {
        print("why is time zone null?  is \(inputTimeZone) invalid?")
    }
} else {
    print("suprise!  newDate is nil")
}
```

Comment: Hmm, the inputTimeZone goes invalid when you go into Daylight Saving. Am investigating....